# NLTK Naive bayes Classifier weird results

Tags: python, machine-learning, nltk

I'm trying to use a nltk naive classifier to classify genres of movies. I am however getting some weird results. Currently it only guesses based on amount of genre inputted.

If I input two action movies, and one comedy every guess will be action. Naturally I want it to based on inputted text:

```
def RemoveStopWords(wordText):
   keep_list = []
   for word in wordText:
        if word not in wordStop:
            keep_list.append(word.lower())

   return set(keep_list)

def getFeatures(element):

   splitter=re.compile('\\W*')
   f = {}
   plot = [s for s in RemoveStopWords(splitter.split(element['imdb']['plot']))
   if len(s)>5 and len(s) < 15]

   for w in plot:
           f[w]= w

   return f

def FindFeaturesForList(MovieList):
    featureSet = []
    for w in MovieList:
        print w['imdb']['title']
        try:
            for genre in w['imdb']['genres']:
                featureSet.append((getFeatures(w), genre))
        except:
            print "Error when retriving genre, skipping element"

    return featureSet

featureList = FindFeaturesForList(trainset)
cl = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(featureList)
```

So whenever I do a cl.classify(movie) it returns the most frequent inputted genre, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using two comedies and one action movie seems like too small a training set. Have you tried training the classifier with *at least* a few hundred movies?

Comment: Yes, i have tried with several hundreds, but when looking at the data, the guess is exclusive based on the amount of genres, not the text inputted.

Comment: Can you post `cl.show_most_informative_features(5)`?

Comment: sure :) Most Informative Features
                  french = u'french'       Music : Comedy =      9.7 : 1.0
                handsome = u'handsome'     Music : Comedy =      9.7 : 1.0
                 germany = u'germany'      Music : Comedy =      9.7 : 1.0
                  kilmer = u'kilmer'       Music : Comedy =      9.7 : 1.0
                 heroine = u'heroine'      Music : Comedy =      9.7 : 1.0

These seem valid enough, but i think i have a problem of how i save the getfeatures.

Comment: This is probably something simple, but dont know where to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the movie review [classification example](http://nltk.org/book/ch06.html) in the nltk book notice that the frequency of all the words from all the movies was collected, and then only the most common words were chosen to be feature keys.

```
all_words = nltk.FreqDist(w.lower() for w in movie_reviews.words())
word_features = all_words.keys()[:2000]
```

I think it is important to note that this is a *choice*. It is not mandatory that the feature keys be chosen this way. Some other clever choice of features could possibly lead to an even better classifier. Choosing good features is the art behind the science.

Anyway, perhaps try using the same idea in your classifier:

```
def getFeatures(text, word_features):
    text = text.lower()
    f = {word: word in text for word in word_features}
    return f


def FindFeaturesForList(MovieList):
    featureSet = []
    splitter = re.compile('\\W*')
    all_words = nltk.FreqDist(
        s.lower()
        for w in MovieList
        for s in RemoveStopWords(splitter.split(w['imdb']['plot']))
        if len(s) > 5 and len(s) < 15)
    word_features = all_words.keys()[:2000]
    for w in MovieList:
        print w['imdb']['title']
        try:
            for genre in w['imdb']['genres']:
                featureSet.append(
                    (getFeatures(w['imdb']['plot'], word_features), genre))
        except:
            print "Error when retriving genre, skipping element"

    return featureSet
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback. 

I definitely see the idea of this. And it could improve the classifier. But currently it does not change the outcome. - every input is currently guessed to be the same genre. Which is the genre that the classifier has been trained with the most times.

Comment: @TheTango You should try to keep your training set balanced. I'm not aware of any 'official' stance to the number of instances you should have when training a model. But from my experiences I have always found better accuracy when I have an identical number of samples for each output class. When I have an unbalanced set I see a drop in performance.

Comment: @steve is it a thing that the training set needs to be balanced? i always assumed that you need a certain number of items from each class, but should not mess with the algorithm, should it?